# why is there no cavity in the whole chicken I just bought?

Tags: chicken

I wanted to try a chicken-with-stuffing recipe, so I bought a ["Tyson Premium Young Chicken (without neck or giblets)"](http://www.tyson.com/Products/Young-Chicken.aspx) from WalMart, but when I unwrapped the chicken to stuff it for the recipe, I don't see a cavity to stuff anything into. I am looking in between the legs, but the only dent there is the one I literally carve out with my knife as I try to open up the chicken.

The chicken was taken out of the freezer and into the fridge this morning (about 10 hours ago) -- in case that matters at all.

Am I just being a noob, or is there some reason why a whole chicken really would not have a cavity pre-made?

Comment: Unless somebody crushed your chicken, or it wasn't cleaned out... there'll be a cavity in there... It should be right between the legs by the "pope's nose" (chicken butt). Is it still frozen?

Comment: The inside of the chicken is frozen still.

Comment: My guess is that the area around the cavity is just a little frozen.

Comment: And it might be filled with giblets, which could feel quite solid frozen...

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right end?

Comment: I think once you let it defrost (in the fridge, preferably), you'll be able to move the legs and/or skin flap and find the cavity. If not, please post JPEGs of this mutant chicken...

Comment: I used to work a rotisserie. Some chickens we received were partially frozen and I found that the way they were packed, the ribs probably broke and the center had collapsed and froze together. In order to get it open, I ran some warm water along the butt and wiggled my fingers through the center.

Answer (score 3):

They usually stuff the cavity with the giblets/neck so you can eat/make gravy/give to cat whatever. You do have to thaw it out a bit to finagle it out of there but once you pull that out you'll have a stuffing-ready cavity. :) happy roasting!